# loop the image with raphael scale down? bind image with raphael exist in html code?

Tags: jquery, raphael

Below code is how to loop the image in raphael

```
var paper = Raphael('canvas', 1000, 1000);
for(i=1; i<=2; i++){
    var r_img = paper.image('img/'+i+'.jpeg', 100, 100, 200, 200);
    paper.freeTransform(r_img).setOpts({drag:'self', scale:true, rotate:true, draw:[ 'bbox' ]});
}
```

I have 2 question:
**1. How to set image width/height scale down as original image?**
**2. Is it possible to bind the image exist in html code?**
  `<div class="canvas">
    <img src="...">
   </div>`
**update**
Now we use Raphael to catch the image is type path in `paper.image('path'...)`, then it will create a `image` tag in `<canvas>`/`<svg>`/.
Is it possible if already a `<img>` tag in html, then Raphael freetransform catch the image use that tag, not create a new `<image>` tag in `<canvas>`/`<svg>`/.

Below code is what I tried for question 1. but seems not work, and question 2. I have no idea how to do it, any suggestion?

```
var paper = Raphael('canvas', 1000, 1000);
var img = new Image();// for get the image width/height before
for(i=1; i<=1; i++){
    img.src = 'img/'+i+'.jpeg';
    img.onload = function(){
        var newwidth = this.width;
        var newheight = this.height;
        var r_img = paper.image('img/'+i+'.jpeg', 100, 100, newwidth, newheight);
        paper.freeTransform(r_img).setOpts({drag:'self', scale:true, rotate:true, draw:[ 'bbox' ]});
    }
}
//html
<div id='canvas'></div>
//dir
img/1.jpeg, 2.jpeg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Move **img.src** after **img.onload**

```
for(i=1; i<=1; i++){
    img.onload = function(){
        var newwidth = this.width;
        var newheight = this.height;
        var r_img = paper.image('img/'+i+'.jpeg', 100, 100, newwidth, newheight);
        paper.freeTransform(r_img).setOpts({drag:'self', scale:true, rotate:true, draw:[ 'bbox' ]});
    }
    img.src = 'img/'+i+'.jpeg';
}
```

This is needed because if you first set **src** and only then define **onload** - image is already loaded so **onload** never fires.

**2)** Question is not clear - could you tell it in other words?

Comment: 1) is solve Thanks a lot!!  2) please see my question update.

Comment: Why don't you want to load image again by Raphael, what's wrong even if it was loaded in HTML already? If you care about traffic - I think second time image will be taken from browser's cache and not loaded from server. If image is not added into svg container then it's not SVG element and it's not anyhow related to Raphael. You can put it over svg container with absolute CSS positioning but you have to do it by yourself via javascript.